# Is there a way in WebStorm (or some other IDE) to do a regex-based stateful replace?

Tags: regex, text-editor

Let's say I need to replace all of the following strings

"x1"
"x2"
"x3"

with

"x1 y1"
"x2 y2"
"x3 y3"

I'd use a wildcard to **search** (e.g. x*) but how to **re-use the text matched by the wildcard** in **replace**? (I don't have particular preferences as for IDES/editors as long as they are cross platform)

i.e. instead of replacing manually x1 -> x1 y1, x2 -> x2 y2 etc., I want do this operation in **one time only**.

I know with regex [you can](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) use a **backref to re-use capture blocks**, but I have no idea how to use it in a editor.

Comment: it's used the same way in webstorm. Make sure you have the "regex" flag checked when using replace. Make sure you have capturing groups in your find value. Use the regex placeholders in your replace value.

Comment: and what is the way? I tried myself before asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Webstorm doesn't change the way you would use regex, or the way regex work. The only thing that changes is the GUI.

- press `ctrl+r` to activate the replace tool in the active file. Or `shift+ctrl+r` to activate the replace tool for an entire directory. (*these shortcuts may be different if you changed your key mappings*)
- Make sure you have the "regex" flag checked when using replace.
- Make sure you have capturing groups in your find value.
- Use the regex placeholders in your replace value.

Comment: I see a red box in your image (which is exactly what I got when i tried). Also I see no wildcard. can you please provide a complete solution based on the example I provided?

Comment: The redbox means there is no match in the file (or directory) in which you are trying to replace content.
I've added a one-time change based on your request.

Comment: @dragonmnl if this has answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. thank you

Comment: you're totally right Sebastien. I usually accept the answers (meritocracy :) ) . I just didn't have time to try your solution. I'll so that asap and accept the answer!

Comment: can you just please explain how the regex you used actually work? (what is captured and how to use $<number>?

Comment: a group inside parenthesis is "captured", each capture has an integer placeholder which is incremented as each capture is made. In my code $1 = (x), $2 = (1|2|3) which is capture 1 OR 2 OR 3.